# Goldfish die in hours

Tags: pond, goldfish

I've had a pond for several months. Up until this week, there have been hundreds of toad tadpoles living in it. However, fish continually die in the pool. Not sure what to do. I left one in the plastic bag with half pet store water and half pond water and it looks fine. I have a pump in the pond, could it be that the pump is too powerful for fish to survive? The tadpoles seemed to survive fine.
[Pond](https://goo.gl/photos/5XLafufxHFyPiY8k7)

Comment: Have you tested the water? http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water-parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the pump is not the reason your fish die. Please test your pond water and tell us these parameters: pH, nitrite and ammonia. These are the most important parameters of the water, you might get the test kit from your fish supplier or a pet store.

I do say the pump and the waterflow is not the reason your fish die, because it is not likely your fish are going to be hurt by fast flowing water. I do have a garden pond of 33000 litres of water and a waterflow of 45000 litres per hour from my two pumps. It is also of interest if your fish supplier can provide the water parameters of the tank(s) your fish came from.

There is always a reason for fish to get ill, usualy it is the water parameters - the water might get poisonous for the fish if ammonia or nitrite is too high.

Comment: I took some water up to Pet Smart and she said the water quality was perfect. So it might just be predators killing the fish.